# Cannot write to samba share with certain name

Tags: mount, samba, smb

***TL;DR:** What else (besides file ownership / `read only = no` in smb.conf) could prevent samba from permitting write access to a share? How does the share name affect the permissions?*

So I've got Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS (samba version is 4.3.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) with an USB device mounted on /mnt/storage. The `mount` output is

```
/dev/sdb1 on /mnt/storage type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
```

All files in the directory `/mnt/storage` are owned and writable by the user `htpc`:

```
htpc@htpc:~$ ls -l /mnt/

insgesamt 16
drwxrwxr-x 13 htpc htpc 4096 Sep  8 23:26 storage

htpc@htpc:~$ ls -l /mnt/storage/

insgesamt 108
drwxr-xr-x 21 htpc htpc  4096 Mär 16 20:55 somedirectory
-rw-r--r--  1 htpc htpc  3870 Sep 11 09:02 somefile.txt
drwxr-xr-x 24 htpc htpc  4096 Apr 10 00:25 ...
```

Here's my smb.conf share (all other settings are kept to their default):

```
[Media]
path = /mnt/storage
comment = HTPC Media server
valid users = htpc
read only = no
browseable = yes
```

I created a samba user with `sudo smbpasswd -a htpc`.

The share can be accessed with Windows 10 but I don't have write permission (creating, deleting and modifying of files are not permitted). The strange thing is **that I don't have that issue when I share any other directory** (e.g. create a plain directory `/opt/testshare` and share that directory the same way like above).

**EDIT**

**This is so strange.**
The problem was not the usb device, it was the share name "Media".

For whatever reason, the share is read only **when I name it "Media"**.
I found [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/724916/can-read-but-cannot-write-to-samba-share) and [this thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/214279/samba-with-active-directory-shares-are-readonly-nt-status-media-write-protect/557028#557028) which have similar problems but they come to the conclusion, that the share and the directory cannot have the same name. I first thought it was a client problem (windows remembers the old uids from the previous installation) but I have the same problems with my phone (ES File Explorer) which I never used to connect to my server before. Even when I use `smbclient` to connect and try to make a directory I get the following error:

```
smb: \> mkdir test
NT_STATUS_MEDIA_WRITE_PROTECTED making remote directory \test
```

I increased the log level to 10 and found this:

```
[2016/09/17 09:15:35.902089, 10, pid=24086, effective(0, 0), real(0, 0), class=passdb] ../source3/passdb/pdb_get_set.c:495(pdb_set_user_sid)
  pdb_set_user_sid: setting user sid S-1-5-21-30211493-2420603996-3020390900-1003
[2016/09/17 09:15:35.902143, 10, pid=24086, effective(0, 0), real(0, 0), class=passdb] ../source3/passdb/pdb_compat.c:73(pdb_set_user_sid_from_rid)
  pdb_set_user_sid_from_rid:
    setting user sid S-1-5-21-30211493-2420603996-3020390900-1003 from rid 1003
[2016/09/17 09:15:35.902216, 10, pid=24086, effective(0, 0), real(0, 0), class=passdb] ../source3/passdb/pdb_get_set.c:557(pdb_set_group_sid)
  pdb_set_group_sid: setting group sid S-1-5-21-30211493-2420603996-3020390900-513
[2016/09/17 09:15:35.902291,  4, pid=24086, effective(0, 0), real(0, 0)] ../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:439(pop_sec_ctx)
  pop_sec_ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2016/09/17 09:15:35.902351, 10, pid=24086, effective(0, 0), real(0, 0)] ../source3/smbd/share_access.c:237(user_ok_token)
  user_ok_token: share Media is ok for unix user htpc
[2016/09/17 09:15:35.902405, 10, pid=24086, effective(0, 0), real(0, 0)] ../source3/smbd/share_access.c:284(is_share_read_only_for_token)
  is_share_read_only_for_user: share Media is read-write for unix user htpc
[2016/09/17 09:15:35.902508, 10, pid=24086, effective(0, 0), real(0, 0)] ../libcli/security/access_check.c:337(se_file_access_check)
  se_file_access_check: MAX desired = 0x2000000 mapped to 0x80120089
[2016/09/17 09:15:35.902558,  5, pid=24086, effective(0, 0), real(0, 0)] ../source3/smbd/uid.c:163(check_user_share_access)
  falling back to read-only access-evaluation due to security descriptor
```

Comment: How are you connecting to the share from windows? Do you mount it as `htpc`?

Comment: Yes, there is no access via guest account and windows asks for username / password. When I create a file on the `/opt/testshare` the owner of the created files is `htpc`. So there must be an issue with accessing mounted external devices?

Comment: Increase the log level and see what SAMBA tells you

Comment: Done. The only messages in the log are the quote warnings above.